# Delete first inserted record

Tags: sqlite

I have a table where the primary key is the current time.  Records will be installed approximately once per minute.  How can I delete the first inserted record (i.e. the oldest which will also have the lowest PK)?

Note that I will be inserting a record after deleting one.  My purpose is limit how many records the table will have and in turn limit the amount of hard drive used.  Will https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html be necessary after each delete?

Comment: SQLite will automatically reuse free space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE date = (SELECT date FROM mytable ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1)
```

To delete the oldest record.